# Edit job outside of talend studio

Tags: talend

i have a big job defined in talend studio. It works
well. But now I have to make another job with only
some changes in prefixes in sqlrequests as destination
tables.

My plan was to export the job and edit the job in my
emacs editor and use the easy way to find and replace
the prefix and reimport this job in talend with another 
name. I tried it. But talend studio shows me a dialog
with invalid job message.

Is it possible in general to edit jobfiles (jobname.item and jobname.properties) utside of talend studio and reimport it? 
Or are there issues and mechanism in talend which prevent this 
way like protect jobfiles with hashes and so on?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to edit an item file, but risky.

I advise you to duplicate your big job in Talend Studio, copy the content of the item file from your big job and paste it into the new one with the correction.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it sometimes but  no success. After my tryouts with external editor I did it  with the duplicate function hand some handcrafted changes in all sql requests. Perhaps in new versions of talend studio it will be possible to do it in another way.